# Generate table from diagram in MagicDraw

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, magic-draw

I see that Magic Draw supports both graphical and tabular notations. However, I would like to know if they can be synchronized to one another or they only function separately. So, if I create a class diagram with the graphical editor, can I generate a table from it in MagicDraw? And whenever I make the changes to one editor, the changes to be reflected in the other editor?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is complex.

First, diagrams are views of the model. Tables, as just another kind of diagrams, are therefore views of the model. In other words, changing an element in a table will change the element in any diagram it is displayed.

Now it gets complex - but how you use the tool can simplify the. You seemed to ask, can a table be synchronized with a table and a table with a diagram? A table can be based on a scope, a query, or by composition (drag an element onto the table or create on the table). Scope or query is is a lot better because they can be used to match the diagram or package where the diagram puts its data (by default, the package where the diagram is stored).

However, diagrams are intended to be expressions of the human for us humans. Thus the diagram does not automatically add elements if they were added in a table.

How do we square the circle? How do we add (or even detect) an element created on a diagram? There is a way to get a list of diagrams (https://community.nomagic.com/usage-in-diagram-displayed-in-generic-table-t5789.html ). Using a similar technique a rule could be created to warn about elements that are not on any diagram. It is still up to you to add the element to the diagram with this information at hand (or write a fancy plugin).

Comment: Here is another link to the documentation for the Usage functions:  https://docs.nomagic.com/display/MD2021xR1/Built-in+operations Look toward the bottom of the page. When researching this I found that there is a new version of the function that was created to limit the search to criteria (usually the diagram type, but could include scope as well) that speeds up the query.